# Returning min score

Tags: python, grouping, min

This is my code that makes groups from a number of members, then rates each group then sums them to get an overall score for the 4 groups in this case.

```
import random

def run(members, n_groups):
    participants = list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
    random.shuffle(participants)

    my_groups = list(zip(*[iter(participants)]*members))
    print(my_groups)

    def get_rating(group):
        return (len(set(group)))

    score = ((sum(get_rating(g) for g in my_groups)))
    print(score)
    return score

members = 4
n_groups = 4

print(min(run(members, n_groups) for _ in range(10)))
```

Output:

```
[(3, 3, 4, 1), (4, 2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2, 4), (1, 1, 4, 2)]
13
[(3, 1, 1, 4), (2, 3, 2, 4), (1, 4, 1, 2), (3, 2, 4, 3)]
12
[(2, 4, 4, 1), (3, 3, 1, 3), (3, 1, 2, 2), (4, 4, 2, 1)]
11
[(3, 1, 4, 1), (3, 1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 4, 4), (3, 2, 3, 4)]
11
[(1, 1, 3, 1), (2, 2, 3, 1), (3, 2, 4, 4), (4, 4, 3, 2)]
11
[(3, 2, 1, 2), (4, 1, 3, 4), (4, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 4, 3)]
14
[(2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 4, 4, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (3, 3, 4, 2)]
12
[(3, 3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 4, 4, 2), (4, 1, 1, 4)]
10
[(1, 4, 3, 2), (4, 2, 3, 3), (3, 1, 2, 1), (4, 4, 1, 2)]
13
[(2, 4, 1, 3), (3, 2, 2, 3), (1, 4, 1, 3), (1, 4, 2, 4)]
12
10
```

So each group gets a rating then the min score is displayed at the bottom, is there a way that I can reprint the group that got that min score after? Since if I try with 100,000 its very hard for me to check each one to find which group it came from!

I tried:

```
import random

def run(my_groups, score):
    participants = list(range(1,members+1))*n_groups
    random.shuffle(participants)

    my_groups = list(zip(*[iter(participants)]*members))
    print(my_groups)

    def get_rating(group):
        return (len(set(group)))

    score = ((sum(get_rating(g) for g in my_groups)))
    print(score)
    return score

members = 4
n_groups = 4

print(min(run(members, n_groups) for _ in range(10), key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

But this returns "Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument" for the bracket by run?

Comment: So you want to keep track of which group produces the smallest score?

Comment: Yeh so at the end: for this case, 10 then [(3, 3, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3, 3), (2, 4, 4, 2), (4, 1, 1, 4)], the group it came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random


def run(members, n_groups):
    participants = list(range(1, members + 1)) * n_groups
    random.shuffle(participants)

    my_groups = list(zip(*[iter(participants)] * members))
    return my_groups


def get_rating(group):
    return len(set(group))


def score(my_groups):
    return sum(get_rating(g) for g in my_groups)


best = min(*(run(4, 4) for _ in range(10)),
           key=score)
print(best)
print(score(best))
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `run` to return `my_groups, score`.

Then change

```
min(run(members, n_groups) for _ in range(10))
```

to

```
min((run(members, n_groups) for _ in range(10)), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

This makes it so that [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min) returns the entire `(my_groups, score)` tuple, but only compares `score` (the second element of the tuple) to find the minimum value.

Comment: Hi thanks! Tried this, put it in the edit of the post can you see whats going wrong?

Comment: Although the error you got should tell you enough about how to fix the issue

Comment: Sounds like you didn't do the first part of the answer